# Redirect 301 for end of URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a domain that is `www.test.com/event/eventName/Current-Info` and I want this ones to redirect to `www.test.com/event/eventName/Current-Registers` .

I tried by doing:

`Redirect 301 /Current-Info /Current-Registers/` but it's not working. Any hint of how to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Filename: .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule www.test.com/event/eventName/Current-Registers www.test.com/event/eventName/Current-Info [R=301,L]
```

Another way

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/Current-Registers$ www.test.com/event/$1/Current-Info [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(event/[^/]+)/Current-Info /$1/Current-Registers [L,NC,R=302]
```